# How to add to a dictionary through my text file

Tags: python, text, dictionary

My text file looks like this:

```
{'testyear3': 20, 'testyear6': '0', 'testyear5': '0', 'testyear4': '0'}
```

It will always look like this, I cannot change the order of the text file or how it is placed as during my program, I write a dictionary that is made to the text file with the code

```
with open ("totals.txt", 'w') as f27:
  f27.write(str(totaldict))
```

therefore at the end of the program the text file always reverts to the order above. How would I go about writing the text file to a dictionary in the format that it is in? Or would I have to change the way I write to the text file?

Comment: if the key is always "testyearX" then why are you using a dictionary and not a list? Lists will preserve the order, and will simplify getting an entry

Comment: ... or an `OrderedDict` ... or a Pandas `DataFrame` ... or ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to change the way you write your dictionary to a text file. The JSON format would be much easier to process (with the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)):

```
import json

# saving
with open("totals.txt", 'w') as f27:
    json.dump(totaldict, f27)

# loading
with open("totals.txt", 'r') as f27:
    totaldict = json.load(f27)
```

However, a dictionary does not maintain any specific order; they are unordered collections *by design*. If you wanted to store items in a specific order, you'd have to either use a different data structure (like a list), or sort your information and use a custom format.

Comment: Does python not have a `LinkedHashMap` type of structure?

Comment: @SteveP.: You mean [`collections.OrderedDict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)? If written out as JSON, you won't preserve ordering when read again as a regular dictionary will be created from that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: you can use `object_pairs_hook`, though.

Comment: @DSM: Sure, but then you are no longer using the JSON standard, really. Any other program reading the data would be perfectly within its right to ignore the key order.

Comment: @DSM: When using JSON and you want to preserve order: write out an ordered *list* of key-value pairs. Don't try to bend the standard.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: what's the old rule?  Be strict in what you produce, and generous in what you accept?  I'm not recommending it as policy, simply noting that there's a keyword argument which makes it possible to preserve the ordering when read again.

Comment: I'm really new to python, sorry, would I have to download json or is it something that is built in with python? i'm using Python 3.3.2

Comment: @user3112327: The module is included with Python; I updated the link to point to the Python 3 version.

Comment: New error upon start:
"totaldict = json.load(f30)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 274, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 352, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 368, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

Comment: @user3112327: the code won't load your old file format; I assumed you'd write a new file first with the data. Your old format is not compatible.

Comment: JSON looks a lot like Python, but with double quotes. But you could have copied the dictionary source into a Python script, and have `json.dump()` write the format for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use python's native parser:

```
def read_dict( fname, src = None):
  if src is None :
    src = StringIO.StringIO(fname)
  src_global = { }
  locals =  {}
  comp_obj = compile(src, fname, 'exec')
  eval(comp_obj, src_global, locals)
  return locals
```

This loads a file, and basically parses it, and then returns local variables created during parsing.

You would need to prepend your code with some variable name, and then return this variable instead of `locals`.

Of course it might be an overkill, but I have file with few dictionaries in format of python script. I guess it's one way to do it.

Comment: Don't. Not when there is `ast.literal_eval` instead. But generally speaking, a standard format like JSON is much better.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well I contain all the variables. I know that executing arbitrary scripts is not best idea. And I was kind of forced to stick to format, due to previous decisions. Although I am keen to switch for future. I'll look into `literal_eval`.